# How to change the front page & component image from the backend? how to get HTML tag attributes in php?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frontend, backend, octobercms

my model Settings.php

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    public $implement = ['System.Behaviors.SettingsModel'];
    // A unique code
    public $settingsCode = 'dca_plugins_settings';
    // Reference to field configuration
    public $settingsFields = 'fields.yaml';
    /**
     * @var array Relations
     */
    public $attachOne = [ 'avatar' => ['System\Models\File'] ];
}
```

my Fields.yaml

```
fields:
  id:
    label: ID
    disabled: true

  avatar:
    label: Avatar
    type: fileupload
    mode: image
    imageHeight: 150
    imageWidth: 250
```

my Component comp.php

```
public $avatar_id = 1;

public function getAvatarImage($avatar_id)
{
    $var = \System\Models\File::select('disk_name')->where('attachment_id', $avatar_id)->first();           
    if (count($var) == 0) return "";

    return $var->path;
} 

function setMyAvatarId($id)
{
    $this->avatar_id = $id;
}
```

my html default.htm

```
{% set avatar_id= __SELF__.property("avatar_id") %}

{% if avatar_id is not empty %}
{% do __SELF__.setMyAvatarId(avatar_id) %}
{% endif %}

<img id="avatar-image" alt="Virtual agent avatar" src="{{ __SELF__.getavatarImage(avatar_id) }}">
<script>
var avatar_id = {{ avatar_id }};
</script>
```

I manage to get a random link but the image is not shown
[image: I manage to get a random link but the image is not shown]

[image: backend - model settings]

backend - model settings

Does anyone know how to define page properties? How do I link my page to the model settings?

How do I make it work? Someone pls help me~~ I'm so lost :(

Answer (score 1):

To change the image you can add this to your model:

```
public $attachOne = ['avatarImage'];
```

and you don't have to create a column in the database called `avatarImage` because October will automatically store your image in another table called 'system_files' or something like that.
So in your fields.yaml you'll have to add this:

```
avatarImage:
     type: mediafinder
     mode: image
     label: My Avatar
```

Then October will create a mediafinder form widget in your settings controller in the control panel and you can change it.
And to show the image in your frontend page you will have to add some code in the php code section of the page

```
$this['settings'] = //The Code to Get the Model;
```

And easily you can display the image using getPath() method.

```
<img src="{{ settings.getPath() }}" />
```

If the above code didn't work you can replace it with:

```
<img src="{{ settings.getPath()|media" />
```

I think the second one will work correctly, I didn't use october for a while :D

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try it later. Btw, do you know how to set unique id for components? so that when I duplicate the component_1, both of the components(component_1 & another component_1) can work normally on the same page.

Comment: I've made some changes to my post. Could you pls have a look at it? Thank you :)

Comment: Actually you cannot set the avatar id this way. But anyway check the source code of the page if you got the real file name of the image but the path is not a complete path you may have to add `|media` to the src in your frontend.

If you can provide me a screenshot of the source code of the page displayed I may understand and help you more.

Comment: I found out that the link was the 1st entry source, do you know how to get the last entry source? cause in my comp.php I put "$var = \System\Models\File::select('disk_name')->where('attachment_id', $avatar_id)->first();" I think is because of the "first()" but I've tried changing it to "last()" but it is not working.