# How do I display image from php function?

Tags: php, image, components, octobercms

How do I display image from the php function? [updated]

default.htm

```
<img id="avatar-image" alt="Jason's Image" src="{{ getAvatarImage() }}" />
```

Component.php

```
public function getAvatarImage()
{
    $var = \System\Models\File::select('disk_name')->where('attachment_id', $avatar_id)->first();       

    if (count($var) == 0) return "";

    return $var->path;
}
```

How do I get the image source and display the image?

Comment: add `echo`  while function calling and Try: `<img id="avatar-image" alt="Jason's Image" src="{{ echo __SELF__.getAvatarImage(avatar_id);  }}" />`

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: where does `avatar_id` come from (in default.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure that this function returns the correct file path? I'll consider that **yes**.

So, organizing things, what you're trying to do is use a custom function inside [Twig environment](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes#twig-section).

To do so you need to register your function in the CMS [extending twig](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#extending-twig).

---

**STEP 1**

Create a `registerMarkupTags()` method that returns an array of custom functions assigned by the "function name" in the plugin registration class.

**YourPlugin/Plugin.php**

```
public function registerMarkupTags() {
  return [
    'functions' => [
      'getAvatarImage' => [ $this, 'getAvatarImageInternal' ]
    ]
  ];
}
```

**STEP 2**

We are referring the custom function to `$this`, so add the method in the same class.

**YourPlugin/Plugin.php**

```
public function registerMarkupTags() {
  return [
    'functions' => [
      'getAvatarImage' => [ $this, 'getAvatarImageInternal' ]
    ]
  ];
}

/**
 * Example of registering a Twig function.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAvatarImageInternal() {
  // Your function body goes here.
  $path = 'http://app.localhost/storage/image.jpg';
  return $path;
}
```

**STEP 3**

Now the custom function is registered and you can use inside Twig environment.

```
<img src="{{ getAvatarImage() }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `getAvatarImage` is not a `static` Method. This means you need an instance of it to be able to call it. Second; to display the Image, you need to echo it back to get the return value (not just call it). Your code should have read something like this:

```
<?php
    $avatar_id  =  10; // JUST A SIMPLE SIMULATION. YOU SHOULD HAVE A WAY TO GET THE ID
    $obj        = new ClassContainingGetAvatarImageMethod();
    $imgURL     = $obj->getAvatarImage($avatar_id);
 ?>

   <img id="avatar-image" alt="Jason's Image" src="<?php echo $imgURL;?>" />
```

OR

```
   <img id="avatar-image" alt="Jason's Image" src="<?php 
    avatar_id = 10; // WHATEVER THE AVATAR_ID MAY BE
    $obj      = new ClassContainingGetAvatarImageMethod();
    echo $obj->getAvatarImage($avatar_id);?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good way to select the image directly from the file system. Instead you can use attachments system as I explained in this question
[How to change the front page & component image from the backend? how to get HTML tag attributes in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428114/how-to-change-the-front-page-image-from-the-backend-how-to-get-html-tag-attribu)